# Android layout ignoring gravity attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i have a couple list items.  one works, the other one doesn't, and they both look fairly identical.  this really should be a game of "spot the difference" in the XML files but i can't, for the life of me, figure out what's wrong.  one of the list items is perfect and the other refuses to justify some of the Views on the right side of the layout, as indicated in the xml.  here's what they each look like with code included.

[image]

^ list_view_item_2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text_product"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text_total"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text_units"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text_uom"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_acog"
                android:text="COG:"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text_acog"
                android:paddingLeft="1sp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This next layout is the one that works.

[image]

^ inventory_child_item.xml:
and the code looks identical, for the most part...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ici_site"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ici_units"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ici_uom"
                android:paddingLeft="1sp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ici_total"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ici_price"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [match_parent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) to `ListView`

*like:*

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: lul.  parent view changed.  crisis averted.

Answer (score 1):

MoonlightCheese,

The only difference I can find in your code is: in the layout that works, your TextView named `@+id/ici_uom` has a padding of `1sp`. For no logical reason can I figure out why this one line would cause any discrepancy as it should not. You will probably be likely to change this value or even add it to the other list and see no difference in behavior. As a result, I am inclined to believe that there is something different with the `ListView`s themselves or their relationships to their parents.

I say this because it is an absolute fact that your list items **are** justifying to the right. It seems that the width is off on a per element basis. The `fill_parent` in the `LinearLayout` should be the indicator. I would reanalyze the lists themselves and potentially how you are populating the views.

Without your parent markups, it is hard to say exactly what is happening and why. This is because we have no idea how you are using the `ListView`s, if there are more than one, if one is a `ListActivity` and the other is not, or even how they are nested.

Based on the difference in appearance, I ***assume*** that you have two `ListView`s and in order to further help you, we would need the markup for them and their parents. Without the markup, that is where I would tell you to look.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: you were spot on man.  it was the parent the whole time.  you saved me bro.

Answer (score 0):

I think the gravity on the textviews doesn't mean anything in your case, because the layout_width is wrap_content, which means, the textview will be as big as your text is. What if you try adding android:layout_gravity="right" to your TableLayout.